# const char * variable pointed to a value inside a function

Tags: c++, arduino, char

I'm using an ESP8266 to code using Arduino. I'm saving a parameter file on flash. Parameter file can be change without changing code.

My question is - do I have to save the value extracted from flash and only then to point it to its final destination inside a class? since that value, the pointer is pointed to lives only inside `readParameters_fromFlash()`

**Example:**

```
A a_instance;
char array_value[30];

// Alternative_1
const char *extract_json(const char *key)
{
    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    File readFile = LittleFS.open(_filename, "r");
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(DOC, readFile);
    readFile.close();

    if (error)
    {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        const char *sensor = "ERR";
        return;
    }
    const char *sensor = doc["key"];
    return sensor;
}
// Alternative_2
void extract_json(const char *key, const char *value)
{
    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    File readFile = LittleFS.open(_filename, "r");
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(DOC, readFile);
    readFile.close();

    if (error)
    {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        value = "ERR";
        return;
    }
    value = doc["key"];
}

void readParameters_fromflash()
{
    /* a_instance.a is a const char* variable */
    a_instance.a = extract_json("key");
}

// Alternative_3
void readParameters_fromflash()
{
    /* a_instance.a is a const char* variable */
    strcpy(array_value, extract_json("key"));
    a_instance.a = array_value;
}
```

Comment: Answer of your question depends on what `extract_json()` does inside and where pointer it returns points to.

Comment: Is `array_value` at the same scope as `a_instance`?  If not, the second one is broken.  `extract_json` returns a pointer... to what?  If it returns a dangling pointer then both of them are broken.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/subscript/#string-duplication), the `char*` is duplicated inside the JsonDocument, so when the `doc` is destructed at the end of the function, the string is destroyed with it. You are returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: @RaymondChen Alternative 1+2 ?

Comment: Applies to both.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm making sure that I fully understand your question- On alternative 3 I actually copy the outcome of `extract_json` (the one that returns a `const char*`). This alternative is the safest, but needs to allocate more space for thae char array (which I suspect as to be duplicate)

Comment: Alternative 2 doesn't work.  Alternative 1 should be ok because the pointer is to contents of an object with static lifetime.

Comment: @BenVoigt The `StaticJsonDocument` does not have static lifetime. It is an automatic variable. For JsonDocument, the "Static" prefix means "fixed memory allocation", suitable for stack allocation. As opposed to DynamicJsonDocument which uses dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @RaymondChen: D'oh, you're right of course